Strapi Cloud deployment error "There was an unknown error response from the API"
I am using Strapi with Vite app as frontend which worked well in local environment. I deployed the Strapi project on cloud.strapi.io and it was built successfully, but when I try to register admin, it shows error as There was an unknown error response from the API.
I don't know what went wrong :(
github folder structure:repo--client--server
Strapi - 4.24.2
NodeJs - 20.14.0

Just changed my code in config/server.js
// host: env("HOST", "0.0.0.0"),
// port: env.int("PORT", 1337),
// url: "http://localhost:1337",
url: "https://<strapi-project-name>.strapiapp.com/",

Adding this URL worked and the project is up and running as expected.

Did you contact the Support team using the widget at the bottom right of the window on cloud.strapi.io?

Yes I searched for the query but it didn't had any solutions so I submitted one.
